# SQLite Delete Slow

Tags: performance, sqlite, sql-delete

I got a SQLite database (First project with SQLite) where I need to delete a bulk of records at once, this is like 14.000 records. The quere is as follows (I changed the names for better read) :

```
delete from table_1 where table_2_id in (
    select id from table_2 where table_3_id in ( 
        select id from table_3
        where (deleted = 1 or
               table_4_id in (select id from table_4 where deleted = 1))));
```

This query takes like 8 minutes to delete. But when I do

```
select * from table_1 where table_2_id in (
    select id from table_2 where table_3_id in ( 
        select id from table_3
        where (deleted = 1 or
               table_4_id in (select id from table_4 where deleted = 1))));
```

it gives me a result in 3 seconds.

I tried using a transaction, cache size, journal mode, but I do not get it to work to get a better performance. What am I missing?

Comment: Create a temporary table (`CREATE TEMP TABLE to_delete AS select table_1_id FROM table1 ...`); how fast is deleting using that (`delete from table_1 where table_1_id in to_delete`)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To create the temporary table it took less then a second, so it seems the performance is correct. To delete the specific data with the query "delete from table_1 where table_1_id in (select id from to_delete)" it then again takes like 8 minutes.

Comment: How large is the database file? How much memory do you have? What file system? Network?

Comment: Currently I have a the folling specs : Size = 30MB, Memory : 8GB, Disk : SSD, System : Windows 7, Network : Local Storage

Comment: 30 MB? Not GB? Do you have a virus scanner?

Comment: It was 30MB and also turned of the virusscanner, but without any result. So I tried multiple things, I copied the database, delete all foreign keys and tried again, and it was much faster. So then I put an index on all foreign keys and it also deleted fast. So this was solution, but I do not know why it then select fast and deletes super slow. But hope this helps anyone!

Comment: Please write this as an answer. Also see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).

Comment: Sqlite seems to have issues with deleting indexed/FK related tables, especially with a self join. Doing PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0; DELETE FROM [MyTable] WHERE [criteria]; PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1; sped up my delete from 960 seconds to about 1.2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution was to divide it to many smaller chunks, and do it again and again until no more rows are affected (sqlite3_changes() returns zero).

Of course this way the operation is not completed sooner, but the table is not locked for too long continuously.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It was 30MB and also turned of the virusscanner, but without any result. So I tried multiple things, I copied the database, delete all foreign keys and tried again, and it was much faster. So then I put an index on all foreign keys and it also deleted fast. So this was solution, but I do not know why it then select fast and deletes super slow. But hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on any of the columns involved? If so, consider dropping it for a large delete and then rebuilding it. If you don't, try adding one.

Answer (score -1):

I have a script in python to delete entries in sqLite DB, lfl is a list of files that I want to delete from DB, in statement speeds process a lot:

```
while len(lfl)>0:
    print ("Deleting entries in DB: ",len(lfl))
    sql="""delete from md5t where file in ('%s')"""%('\',\''.join(tuple(lfl[:500])))
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    del lfl[:500]
```